# How to display response from PHP on HTML page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a text field and a button on the HTML page.
There is also a para tag which will display the error on validation.

If the field is empty it will be changed to
`Name must be filled out`

and it is changing to that on validation.

Now when I input a string and press the submit button....the value should be passed to PHP page and check the condition and print the message accordingly on the HTML page...but when I click submit the message is printed out on the index.php page itself.

How should I use the AJAX code so it prints the message on the para tag with id error?

Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

**HTML CODE**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="java123.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
      <input type="submit">
    </form> 
    <p id="error"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
   <?php
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   if($name == "thistext"){
       $arr = array("sth"=>"hello");
       echo json_encode($arr);
   }else{
       $arr = array("sth"=>"User does not exist");
       echo json_encode($arr);
   }
   ?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
var invalid = 0;

function validateForm() {

/* WHERE SHOULD I PUT THIS CODE
    $.ajax({
      url: "index.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
         $("#error").html(response.sth);
      }
    });

 */

    invalid = 0;

    name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    if(name == ""){
      document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Name must be filled out";
      invalid = 1;
    }else{
      document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
    }

    if(invalid != 0){
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
 }
```

Comment: use jquery for this

Answer (score 1):

```
 function validateForm() {

    invalid = 0;

    name = document.getElementById("name").value;

    if(name == ""){
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Name must be filled out";
        invalid = 1;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";
    }

    if(invalid != 0){
    $.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        $("#error").html(response.sth);
    },
error: function(data){
            console.log("error");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    }
    }
```

Comment: in form write action="#"

Comment: Ok I saw it..You have to send json array through php page...It requires you to echo the json array from php

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function validateForm() {

    var name = $('name').value;

    if(name == ""){
        $('error').innerHTML = "<b>Name must be filled out</b>";

        // you need to send data also
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { 'name': name },
            success: function(res) {
               // $("#error").html(res.sth);
                console.log(res);
            },  
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });

    }else{
        $('error').innerHTML = "";
    }

   /* Always return false because this will prevent actual form submit.
      You are submitting form with ajax. 
   */
   return false

}
```